# java.lang.IllegalStateException: JBWEB000232: Cannot forward after response has been committed Occured

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I am doing login application. I am encrypting the username and password parameters in login jsp and then I am sending it to servlet. In servlet I decrypt the username and password and dispatch to LoginAction page.Code as below

```
if(counter < loginLimit)
{

try{
    String sessionid = request.getSession(false).getId();
    response.setHeader("SET-COOKIE", "JSESSIONID=" + sessionid + "; HttpOnly");
 }
 catch(Throwable t)
{
    GenericExceptionLog.log("DPLoginActionServlet :::: getting error::"+loginId+"  @ "+new java.sql.Timestamp(new java.util.Date().getTime()),"DPLoginActionServlet");
}

RequestDispatcher reqdisp=request.getRequestDispatcher(postLogin);
reqdisp.forward(request,response);
return;
```

}

but it givimg me
java.lang.IllegalStateException: JBWEB000232: Cannot forward after response has been committed Occured

Comment: From a quick glance, that looks fine - more code would help.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, the error you got say everything:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot forward after response has been committed

Before the call `reqdisp.forward(request,response);` you have written data to the `response`-buffer.
And if it is more than the buffer size, then it was committed to the browser.
So it's too late for forwarding.

What you can do:

- look at you code before the `forward()` call and
- find where the response was written

  - move your if-block with the `forward()` up there OR
  - add additional condition block around the response writing